# Module Alamofire has no member named request when being imported in the Podfile

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods, alamofire

I'm developing a Framework for iOS where I need Alamofire but when I'm compiling my framework I got the following error:

```
Module Alamofire has no member named request
```

I also need Dollar in my Framework so here is my Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
link_with  ['VTStarterFramework', 'VTStarterFrameworkTests']
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
pod 'Dollar'
```

I also have set in Build settings the Build Active Architecture Only to

```
Debug = YES
Release = NO
```

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's really weird the error because it doesn't appear an error in the import line. And It let me autocomplete the Alamofire.request but after I write it. It appears this error. I don't know if it could be an issue with the library or something about the architectures but it looks like I installed it properly

Comment: [Hi I answered this over here if it works don't forget to show your gratitude. :)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37652533/1890317)