# Error: Module Alamofire has no member named 'request'

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have installed Alamofire to my project through cocoapods. After opening the project and putting the sample code from Alamofire github, I'm getting this error:

**"Module 'Alamofire' has no member named 'request'**

I have tried all solutions in the thread:
[Module 'Alamofire' has no member named 'request'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549832/module-alamofire-has-no-member-named-request) But couldn't find the solution.

[image]

Comment: Which Swift version are you using?

Comment: Swift 2.2, Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: Did you add the Alamofire tag(3.5.0) which is available with Swift 2.2?

Comment: Yeah. I have installed 3.5.0

Comment: make sure you have open workspace instead of Xproj file

Comment: Sure. I opened xproj file

Comment: no, you have to open .xcworkspace file after installing pods

Comment: I tried that one too :(

Comment: just close the Xcode and reopen using .xcworkspace file from your project folder. clean the project and build again.

Comment: Tried it already!. Not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to XCode 8 with Swift 3.0 and Alamofire version 4.0. Everything working perfectly now

Comment: Well...same configuration here...Xcode8, Swift3, Alamofire 4.0
It works on the device, but not under Simulator.

The annoying thing is that the network part of my app is "done". I have no deed to fiddle with it in any way. I'm just trying to correct some small Autolayout issues, and since I don't have the full spectrum of iPhones on my desk, I thought I can rely on the Simulator.

Comment: I updated my reply. For me, it works on device, not under Simulator though