# Xcode cannot compile for older Architecture

Tags: xcode, macos, compilation, ios11, xcode9

This happens after I updated my Xcode to support iOS 11, if I set 'Build Active Architecture' to 'YES' and build for a specific device, it runs fine but if I try to set 'Build Active Architecture' to 'NO' or build for generic iOS device it will create an error 'No Such Module...'.

This is okay for testing but the main problem is that the version to upload to app store needs to support armv7 and armv7s as well.

<s>If it affects I am using Xcode 9.0.1(no absolute reason just the latest version when I perform the update).</s> I am using the current latest version of 9.2.

I am using Cocoapods to install external frameworks. Those that appear in the 'No such Module' error includes Alamofire, XlPagerTabStrips and ActionsheetPicker(those that I noted, may be more) they are all updated to latest version when I updated Xcode.

There is also another situation where my project cannot use Automatic codes signing, that may or may not be related but I am just going to mention it, if it hints at anything.

**Update:**
I have converted my project to Swift4, confirmed my cocoapods is up to date, reinstalled all the modules for Swift4. Same situation, the error claiming 'No such module...' will appear if I try to compile including older architectures.

The error will not show if I attempt to compile only for arm64 and armv7s but somehow the ipa only supports arm64.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you got the last version of `Xcode 9.1` [*December 4, 2017*] then, you may also first start to update [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/) to the last version, then follow documentation to clean remove then reinstall the last version of each module:

- https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire
- https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip
- https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0
- ...

Remember also that some modules will required some specifics setup to be integrated into your Xcode project using CocoaPods.

Comment: Did you also remove/clean remove and reinstall the last updated version of each modules with Cocoapods ?

Comment: That'll take some time... but I guess I don't have much options either. I only did the normal pod update.

Comment: According to Alamofire, CocoaPods 1.1+ is required to build Alamofire 4.0+. Have you update CocoaPods to last version also ?

Comment: Look like those modules are not properly installed or migrated, or modules was improperly setup to be integrated on you Xcode project (using CocoaPods) ...

Comment: I did a complete reinstall of every module and now the error changed... instead of 'No such module...' It became 'No Type Name...' which are impossible like "No type named 'DataRequest' in module 'Alamofire'" for example XD

Comment: Maybe this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549832/module-alamofire-has-no-member-named-request may help you.