# Alamofire - Swift Compiler Error - Use of undeclared type

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

I am having the same problem but only if I archive the solution. I can build the project and install the app to the device without getting any compile errors.

[Module 'Alamofire' has no member named 'request'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549832/module-alamofire-has-no-member-named-request/37652533#37652533)

Why am I getting 59 errors if I want to archive the project? I cleaned the project, deleted all the derived folder, checked project settings -paths, bitcode = YES / NO etc. None of them fixed the compiler errors. Like I said if I build the app or install it to a device Xcode doesn't give any error for Alamofire. I also did "Build Active Architecture Only" Debug = YES Release = NO.

I cannot archive my project. The following are just 2 compile errors out of 59. All under the Swift Compiler Error. Thanks for your help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you use  import Alamofire ?

Comment: Yes all the swift files on top there is a "import Alamofire". The project is objective C based. Only the rest calls are done by swift.

Comment: I have just found this: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/248 but this question didn't resolve as well. I am having the same one. I have checked my project's architectures. The value is: arm64 armv7 armv7s

Answer (score 1):

Check the requirements of the Alamofire project you are installing. Check if it is not greater than your xcode and swift version. If it does, go back to the Alamofire repo and install the version that is compatible with your  xcode and swift.

When adding the package to your podfile take out the "~>" part as written in Alamofire's github page. Do something like this

```
pod 'Alamofire', '5.0.0-beta.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps someone. The problem was on the root folder I saw a folder named Alamofire and it was empty. I downloaded the latest version from the following url and pasted everything under that folder. I can archive the project now!

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire